Function XLookup not return correct results
How can I lookup a value in 1 sheet, compare the value of column in another sheet, if match found then return the value of column (I), have it displayed in abc.C2, etc for the entire spreadsheet?
=XLOOKUP(ABC.A2,'[Main.xlsx]Master Stories'!$C:$C,'[Main.xlsx]Master Stories'!$I:$I,"Not found",0)
This only returns Not Found. What am I doing wrong?
I have looked at Index/Match & Vlookup
Main.xlsl.Master Stories data sample.



IDS#
EPIC #
EpicNameID
Name




03606
T-56
Claims
T5013-9


03605
T-72
Claims
T5013-9


03603
T-6
Claims
T5013-9



ABC.Stories
Lookup Value = 03606
Return Value = T-56 to be placed in ABC.E2
Repeat process until the entire ABC spreadsheet has been updated.

ABC.A2 isn't a cell reference so I imagine that will also pull the Not Found result? This should read as =XLOOKUP(A2,'[Main.xlsx]Master Stories'!$C:$C,'[Main.xlsx]Master Stories'!$I:$I,"Not found",0) or C2 instead of A2 (I'm not sure from your post which you wanted)

There's so much you haven't told us.  Is the "IDS#" in column C?  Is the "EPIC #" in column I?  Did you mean ABC!A2 to refer to cell A2 on sheet ABC?

I agree with Tim that this is a pretty straight forward problem and formula, so the issue is very likely in the syntax or where you have things pointed. it should read as =xlookup( [lookup cell], [lookup array], [return array] "Not Found",0) So the cell reference is what you're searching for, lookup array is where you're trying to find the value, and return array is what you want to be pulled as a result. Try re-writing the formula and you may have better luck, it seems that first reference may have gotten twisted.

For your table, Assuming it starts at column A. You can do a XLOOKUP as per below
=XLOOKUP(3606,A:A,B:B,"Not Found",0)
Lookup Value (3606) - This is the value you want to search for. You can replace 3606 with a cell reference.
Lookup Array (A:A) - This is the range where the formula will search for the Lookup Value
Return Array (B:B) - This is  the range from which the formula will return a corresponding value
and ""Not Found" will be return if nothing is found.
match mode is set to zero for an exact match (this is always zero in a lookup unless you know what your doing)

Thank you for all the assistance, it works now:
Results:
=XLOOKUP($A3,'[Main.xlsx]Master Stories'!$C:$C,'[Main.xlsx]Master Stories'!$I:$I,"NF",0)
